# Bilateral shift as multiplication operator

Tags: functional-analysis

I've recently saw the following post : [Spectrum bilateral shift](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/971851/spectrum-bilateral-shift)

Highest voted answer mentions that we can realize bilateral shift as a multiplication operator $M_zf(z)=zf(z)$. I tried to justify that statement but the furthest I could go was that since spectrum of bilateral shift is $\sigma(\mathbb T)$, there exists a isometric $*$-isomorphism between the $C^*$ algebra generated by bilateral shift and the identity and set of continuous functions on the gelfand spectrum of this $C^*$-algebra.

From spectral theorem we know that bilateral shift then is unitarily equivalent to a multiplication operator such that $M_zf(z)=zf(z)$ on $L^2(X,\mu)$ where $X$ is the Gelfand spectrum of the $C^*$ algebra generated by bilateral shift and the identity and $\mu$ is a finite measure. But we don't know anything about this measure $\mu$. For instance can we say that $\mu$ is the normalized measure on $\mathbb T$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making this more complicated than what it is.

Let $\{\epsilon_n:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ denote the standard ONB of $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$, so $\epsilon_n=(\dots,0,0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots,0,0,\dots)$ where $1$ lies in the $n$-th position. Also, let $e_n(z)=z^n$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, so $\{e_n: n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is the standard orthonormal basis for $L^2(\mathbb{T})$.

Define a unitary operator $U:\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})\to L^2(\mathbb{T})$ by $U\epsilon_n=e_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and extend linearly and continuously. Since $U$ maps an ONB onto an ONB, it is a unitary operator.

Now take the bilateral shift $T:\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})\to\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ and consider its conjugation with $U$, namely the operator $UTU^*:L^2(\mathbb{T})\to L^2(\mathbb{T})$. Since $T\epsilon_n=\epsilon_{n+1}$, we have that
$$UTU^*e_n=UT\epsilon_n=U\epsilon_{n+1}=e_{n+1}=M_z(e_n)$$
Since $UTU^*$ and $M_z$ agree on the ONB, they agree in general, i.e. $UTU^*=M_z$.